# Массив картинок и обработка после их загрузки

Tags: javascript

Есть массив картинок, которые отбираю по имени класса. Нужно их ресайзить в зависимости от соотношения ширина/высота. Но т.к. не все картинки загружены, когда выполняется скрипт, то `img.width` возвращает 0. Пытаюсь добавить обработку картинок после загрузки, но не выходит - все равно возвращает 0. Где проблема?

```
function img_size() {
  var array = document.getElementsByClassName('mob_img_select');
  console.log(array);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    array[i].onload = onload_img(array[i]);
  }
}

function onload_img(img) {
  console.log(img);
  if (img.width >= img.height) {
    console.log('размер ' + img.width + 'x' + img.height);
    img.className += ' mob_img_width';
  }
  else {
    console.log('размер ' + img.width + 'x' + img.height);
    img.className += ' mob_img_height';
  }
}

img_size()
```

Соответственно, первые картинок 10 обрабатываются нормально и в консоли вижу

> размер 210x210

А остальные выводит

> размер 0x0

Если страницу перезагрузить, то все обрабатывается правильно, т.к. картинки уже в кеше.

Comment: проще было бы на java это делать, потому что там нету неконтролируемой асинхронности

Comment: Вы в свойство `onload` присваиваете результат выполнения функции `onload_img`. То есть функция выполняется сразу же, а не в момент загрузки картинки. В данном случае должно было быть нечто вроде такого: `array[i].onload = (function(i) { return function() { onload_img(array[i]); } })(i);` (внешний `function` для сохранения значения `i`), но лучше всё-таки через `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема №1 в том что Вы присваиваете свойству `onload` не функцию, а результат ее выполнения.

Проблема №2 в том что пытаясь передать `array[i]` параметром - не учитываете асинхронность вызова `onload_image`. На момент  выполнения этого обработчика, значение его аргумента `img` может указывать *не на тот элемент, который был в `array[i]` при установке свойства `onload`*.
Это происходит потому, что цикл `for` выполняется синхронно и не ожидает завершения обработчика - `onload` будет вызвана браузером вне общего синхронного потока. Проще говоря, эта функция выполнится именно в момент события `load`, которое возбудится после полной загрузки изображения.

---

Для того чтобы код заработал, как Вы ожидаете:

Строку

```
array[i].onload = onload_img(array[i]);
```

замените на

```
array[i].addEventListener('load', onload_img);
```

Далее, в обработчике `onload_img()` замените:

- имя переменной `img` на `this` (и уберите аргумент обработчика)
- имя свойства с `height` на `naturalHeight` (если хотите получить высоту изображения, а не высоту элемента)
- имя свойства `width` на `naturalWidth` (соответственно)

---

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', img_size); 
setTimeout(console.clear, 1e4); 

function img_size() {
  let array = document.getElementsByClassName('mob_img_select');
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].dataset.idx = i; 
    array[i].addEventListener('load', onload_img);
  }
}

function onload_img() {
  let w = this.naturalWidth, 
      h = this.naturalHeight; 
  console.log(`размер изображения №${+this.dataset.idx + 1}: ${w}x${h}`);
  if (w >= h)
    this.classList.add('mob_img_width');
  else
    this.classList.add('mob_img_height');
}
```

```html
<img class="mob_img_select" src="https://picsum.photos/400/280/?random">
<img class="mob_img_select" src="https://picsum.photos/160/300/?random">
<img class="mob_img_select" src="https://picsum.photos/100/65/?random">
<img class="mob_img_select" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200/?random">
<img class="mob_img_select" src="https://picsum.photos/200/370/?random">
```

Comment: this указывает на Window

Comment: @Артем, Regent, вы правы - я проглядел способ назначения обработчика. Исправлено. Спасибо за замечания!

Comment: this все равно указывает на Window, и функция onload_img не вызывается если не добавить () к ней в конце

Comment: @АртемАртем зачем добавлять `()`? `array[i].addEventListener('load', onload_img);` прекрасно работает: https://jsfiddle.net/jxyptayj/7/

Comment: @Regent, Вы снова на 100% правы, а мне очень неудобно за свою невнимательность (видимо, пора отложить мобилку с SO, и наконец заняться работой :) ).

Comment: @Regent, Взял ваш код с jsfiddle, и у меня он не работает, пока не добавлю (). Хотя в jsfiddle все корректно. В случае, если добавляю скобки, this указывает на window. Суть всех своих проблем понимаю, но как решить без идей

Comment: @Regent, с внешней функцией для передачи значения i, функция onload_img тоже не запускается, испольковал код из вашего коментария. Муть какая-то)

Comment: @Артем, скобки `()` запустят выполнение функции, и вернут влево ее ***результат***. Это не то что нужно в данном случае. Если скобки не указывать, то получается *ссылка* на функцию, а не результат ее выполнения - как раз то что нужно при назначении обработчика. Касаемо _«понимаю, но как решить без идей»_ - попробуйте выполнить действия, указанные в ответе.

Comment: @АртемАртем если код работает в fiddle, но не работает локально, то проблемы с локальным HTML/JS, которых нет в fiddle.

Comment: @Regent, не знаю прям где искать такую проблему. Проблема в том, что никакая функция не хочет загружаться, если вместо функции написать consol.log('что угодно'), то все обрабатывается и выводится, но если этот же лог засунуть в отдельную функцию, то тишина.

Comment: @АртемАртем если вы про `array[i].addEventListener('load', console.log("Что угодно"))`, то это не серьёзно, ибо с событием загрузки изображения никак не связано. Раньше (а возможно, и сейчас) была проблема, что для кэшированных картинок функция на `onload` не отрабатывала. Решалось это, например, установкой `src` изображения после добавления обработчика события, либо проверкой параметров изображения перед добавлением обработчика события (если ширина не нулевая, то можно сразу использовать картинку). Проверьте - может, у вас проблема из-за кэша.

Comment: @Regent ГОСПОДИ, как всегда проблема элементарная, я забывал сбрасывать кеш, и поэтому ваш код не работал, большое спасибо) посылаю лучи добра